# javascript/css - realize a attitude indicator

Tags: javascript, css, image, indicator

Someone can help me to realize an attitude indicator like this:
http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/6/b./2/1223615301572097144Startright_Attitude_Indicator.svg.med.png
I must utilize it inside an web page html and modify the rotation and the vertical move of the background image.

Tanks

Comment: Your link doesnt work. Is it something like [THIS](http://openclipart.org/people/Startright/Startright_Attitude_Indicator.svg) ?

Comment: @Anth, Stack Overflow is a place to ask for scripting problems, not for a freelancer's job to be done for free.

Comment: I newer try because I don't know how to start to do it. is like this http://openclipart.org/people/Startright/Startright_Attitude_Indicator.svg . Please help me!
It isn't for a freelance job, is for my personal application.

Comment: This is a HUGE issue, not something that can be kludged together quickly. You can even buy the code online for a couple of grand. Google javascript css attitude indicator flight simulation and you'll see.